# How to extract solr index docs

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I need to do some transformations on docs before indexing them in solr. but the texts come from various resources and it's diffcult to do the transformations before indexing because i will have to adapt several programs to parse the files. I'm thinking of indexing them in solr, extract the text fields, do transformations and reindex again.

I tried :

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*&rows=20000&wt=xml&indent=true'
```

but the output is a results xml file while i'm looking for some way to extract the docs with fields like in the posting format. is this possible? how should i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using one of the Solr Clients listed on the [Integrating Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr) page. This will allow you to use your programming language of choice to extract and transform the Solr documents and then reload them into the index.